# How to secure internal Rails API which is also used externally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, reactjs, authentication

Got a Rails app over here which uses React to render certain front-end elements, accessing the database via pre-established REST routes.

These REST routes also provide API access for external calls, which are validated by an auth token.

**The problem:**
With the aforementioned (token) authentication active, the internal API calls are blocked because I am not passing any auth token in the header of these calls.

**Approach #1:**
I can hard-code an auth token in each call but this is undesirable since you can view the source code of the page (and thus the auth token). I have thought about passing it from the Rails controller into the React component but that would lead to the same issue in the previous sentence.

**Approach #2:**
Lastly, I have considered validating (in the same place where I check for a proper auth token) the IP addresss, so that internal API calls do not need an auth token. However, I figure the IP can be spoofed and thus this approach is also flawed aka insecure.

**OK, I'm stuck...**
Any recommendations here for securing a Rails API that is used both internally as well as exposed publicly? I've done a lot of searching both on and off SO but have not found an approach I can utilize with React (which is again making those internal calls). I've thought about splitting the API into two (one for internal requests, the other for external) but I would like to only maintain one API ("eat your own dog food", as an answer on another API related question on SO said).

### Update:

I've decided to use the same api auth token mechanism for authenticating api requests for internal api usage. By internal, I mean the front-end components of the Rails app which are utilizing React to render information for the user. Here's my approach:
1. When the user signs in, grab their api auth token and save it to their cookies.
2. When the user visits a page requiring use of React to render components, grab the cookie from their computer and send it alongside requests in teh header.
3. When the user logs out, delete the cookie from their computer and regenerate their api auth token automatically.

I'd love to hear what you all think of this approach. This is for an "MVP" so didn't want to spend too much time on authentication but also didn't want to leave it open to the world.. (If the MVP proves itself marketable then resources will be invested in making this as watertight as possible)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you need some authentication solution, for rails the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) works great. Your internal APIs must require users to be authenticated.

Next, either you don't ask you public users to be authenticated at all — in that case they will not be able to access the internal APIs.

Either, if you need the authentication for public users, then you need some authorization solution, for rails you can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). In that case the public users should not be authorized to access the internal APIs.

Alternatively, you can limit the access to internal API to IP addresses belonging to your company network only, if it works for you.

Comment: Dmitry I really appreciate the response. My only concern with your recommendation is I want to build & maintain a single API for both internal and external use. I am wondering if it is recommended that both the internal & external use the same authentication mechanism, like an auth token in my case. If so, I have yet find a way to pass the auth token to the react component without it being exposed publicly in the source code of the pages where that API is utilized. P.S. I do want both internal and external use authenticated since it is the same API

Comment: Having a single API for different kinds of consumers is okay, just you must have the authentication system in that case — and that's not a single token for all users, that's a unique token for every user. So the token you expose to your react components should be valid to use the public API only.